# php max excerpt length not must length (exclude html / css)

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem using the below:

```
<?php echo excerpt(15); ?>
```

Because! I have some pages *(unfortunately)* that have on-page styles and little text, not meeting the 15 characters, so what is occurring is the excerpt limit is not being met, so it displays 'a little text.. then `<css> <styles><h1> <h2>`, etc'.

---

**How can I re-write as UP to 15 character limit, or MAX. So if it falls short that's fine. Or to exclude HTML / and CSS?**

---

Excerpt function within **functions.php**

```
function excerpt($limit) {
      $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
      if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($excerpt);
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt).'...';
      } else {
        $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
      } 
      $excerpt = preg_replace('`\[[^\]]*\]`','',$excerpt);
      return $excerpt;
    }

    function content($limit) {
      $content = explode(' ', get_the_content(), $limit);
      if (count($content)>=$limit) {
        array_pop($content);
        $content = implode(" ",$content).'...';
      } else {
        $content = implode(" ",$content);
      } 
      $content = preg_replace('/\[.+\]/','', $content);
      $content = apply_filters('the_content', $content); 
      $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
      return $content;
    }

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'custom_trim_excerpt');

function custom_trim_excerpt($text) { // Fakes an excerpt if needed
global $post;
if ( '' == $text ) {
$text = get_the_content('');
$text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
$text = str_replace(']]>', ']]>', $text);
$text = strip_tags($text);
$excerpt_length = 35;
$words = explode(' ', $text, $excerpt_length + 1);
if (count($words) > $excerpt_length) {
array_pop($words);
array_push($words, '...');
$text = implode(' ', $words);
}
}
return $text;
}
```

Comment: Where does this `excerpt()` function come from?

Comment: maybe you should ask here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three options (possibly more, this isn't meant to be exhaustive)

1. Abandon the wordpress function. By using custom PHP passing the $post->post_content through to your own function you could use PHP's XML manipulation functions, specifically [DOM manipulation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php), or a regular expression to remove certain tags.
2. Do a check on your post content before running excerpt. If you can check for the existence of a tag to start within the first 15 characters by checking for the first position of a "<" character using strpos, then you can use a normal if/else.
3. Using wordpresses functionality properly, you can change how the excerpt is dealt with through filters. You can remove the default functionality and replace it with your own. [This link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141125/allow-html-in-excerpt/141136#141136) in particular is very useful for explaining how to customise your excerpt function in wordpress, specifically with regards to allowing tags or not within the excerpt.